# Trying to make this div rotate on load

Tags: html, css, animation

I can't see what's wrong...but the div is not rotating

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style type="text/css">

        .rotate
        {

            margin:121px 149px;

            width:483px;
            height:298px;

            background:#676470;
            color:#fff;
            font-family:Tahoma;
            font-size:2em;

            text-align:center;

            transition:all 5s ease;

            -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-3240deg);
            -ms-transform: rotateZ(-3240deg);
            transform: rotateZ(-3240deg);

        }

        .rotate div {
            padding-top: 3em;
        }

        .rotate:active
        {
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="rotate"><div>Hello</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you will have to invoke the animation on hover or with keyframes, or with a JS on load or document ready function adding the animation

Comment: @damianocelent Hi and thanks, I do want it to run as soon as the page is loaded, not on a mouse event

Comment: No problem, if you use keyframes, it will start on page load, unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [CSS3 animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Here's a demo of your example:

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.rotate {
  margin: 121px 149px;
  width: 483px;
  height: 298px;
  background: #676470;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  animation: rotateZ 5s;
}
.rotate div {
  padding-top: 3em;
}
@keyframes rotateZ {
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(-3240deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

---

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/68w4528n/)**

Comment: God bless you Ricky